# Hi, how can i find the indices of values that are equal in two different lists?

Tags: python

Because I have a list and an array of strings (166x45) and I want to create a new matrix with the element that have the same values. I have a list of titles (14x1) and a matrix which columns have a title (166x45). Now I want to create a new matrix(166x14) with the element of the great matrix that have the same titles of the list of titles.

Ex:
variables = ["X", "Y", "Z", "W"]

matrix(array of strings) = ["A" "X" "Z"]

```
                      2   .   .
                      .   .   .
                      .   .   .
                      .   .   .
```

New matrix = ["X" "Z"]

I think that it's the same of strfind in matlab.

Comment: Do you want the indices or the elements? If you want the elements only, convert both to a `set` and get the intersection. Also, what do you mean by a "matrix(array of strings)? Is it just a list of strings?

Comment: Hi, I have a list of titles (14x1) and a matrix which columns have a title (166x45). Now I want to create a new matrix(166x14) with the element of the great matrix that have the same titles of the list of titles

Comment: Can you provide code with the a small example of your input data and the expected output (the examples you provided are not actual code and don't show your data structures)? For example, what do you mean by "matrix"? Is it a list of lists or are you using a `numpy` array of strings?

Comment: variables = ["Center", "Radius", "Diameter", "Surface"...] (14x1)   dataArray = ["Center", "Area", "Surface", "Flat"...] (166x45). In dataArray all columns have the title and 165 values. Now I want to create a (165x14) that have only the columns of dataArray that have the same titles that are in variables.

Comment: The array example you provided is a list. What do you mean when you say it is (166 x 45)? Also, please edit your question instead of adding the code as a comment, so the question is useful for others.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I mean 166 rows x 45 columns

Answer (score 1):

If order doesn't matter, you can use Python's `set` type and take intersection (`&`) of the two sets:

```py
common = set(['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'W']) & set(['A', 'X', 'Z'])

common = list(common) # convert set object back to list

print(common) # -> ['X', 'Z']
```